# The cloth isn't on the character when enabling cloth stimulation

Tags: objects, cloth-simulation, collision

By the picture of character you can notice that I'm not an expert in blender, so the issential question i have is
when enabling cloth stimulation for the shirt, it happens to appear somewhere else, but not on my character. I have enabled collision physics for the character itself. He is riggified.
[image]

Comment: Have you determined a pin group for you shirt? It will make it stick and not fall

Comment: @moonboots you don't need a pin group, body as collider should affect the cloth, right?

Comment: Please share your blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com if answer is not working for you.

Comment: oh ok I thought it would bug

Comment: thank you that worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cloth simulation. Select your cloth mesh. Position it where you want it on your character CTRL+A > Apply all transforms. Your cloth's origin will be in the world's origin. Now apply your cloth modifier. Your body should have a collision modifier. Press play on the timeline, your cloth should adjust to the body as you intend.